# Post class is not submitting form data to entity database

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

this is probably a duplicate question but non of the other question's I've seen have been able to help me. My knowledge with asp.net is very limited.

The code below is the Post Class that creates the database.

```
public class Post
    {
        //The post ID
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int postId { get; set; }
        // Foreign key to customer
        [ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
        public string postTitle { get; set; }
        public string postBody { get; set; }
        public string postDescription { get; set; }
        public string postCategory { get; set; }
        public bool postAnonymous { get; set; }
        public string postLikes { get; set; }
        public string postDislikes { get; set; }

        private ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

        public Post()
        {
            this._dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        public void AddToDatabase()
        {
            _dbContext.Posts.Add(this);
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();

        }



    }
```

The code below is the front-end input for the form I'm trying to submit

```
    <div class="jumbotron">
    <p><form id="submitForm" class="form-horizontal">


    <legend class="text-center">Submit a post</legend>

    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content bigModal">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Insert post information below</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">

          <%-- Title--%>
      <label for="inputTitle" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Title:</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
          <asp:TextBox  class="form-control" ID="inputTitle" runat="server" placeholder="Title"></asp:TextBox>
      </div>
      <br/><br/>
           <%-- Body--%>
      <label for="inputBody" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Body:</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
          <asp:TextBox  class="form-control" ID="inputBody" runat="server" placeholder="Body"></asp:TextBox>
      </div>
      <br/><br/>
           <%-- Description--%>
      <label for="inputDescription" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Description:</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
          <asp:TextBox  class="form-control" ID="inputDescription" runat="server" placeholder="Description" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
      </div>
          <br/><br/>
           <%-- Category--%>
      <label for="inputCategory" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Category:</label>
          <asp:ListBox class="form-control" runat="server" id="inputCategory" SelectionMode="Multiple" >
  <asp:ListItem Value="test1" Text="test1"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="test2" Text="test2"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="test3" Text="test3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
          <%--Anonymous--%>
      <label for="inputAnonymous" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Would you like this post to be done anonymously?:</label>
          <asp:RadioButtonList ID="inputAnonymous" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="Yes" Text="Yes">Yes</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="No" Text="No">No</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>


      </div>
      <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>


      </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
        <button id="formSubmit" OnClick="formSubmit_Click" name="formSubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
              </div>


      </div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="width: 127px">Submit a post</button>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Finally, the code below is the C# backend that should submit the information to the database.

```
 public void AddPost()
        {



            Post newPost = new Post()
            {
                postTitle = inputTitle.Text,
                postBody = inputBody.Text,
                postDescription = inputDescription.Text,
                postCategory = inputCategory.SelectedValue,
               postAnonymous = Convert.ToBoolean(Int32.Parse(inputAnonymous.SelectedValue)),
            };
        }
```

I'm unsure as to why this is not working. Is there any obvious errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you neet to call `SaveChanges()` at the end of `AddPost` method

```
public void AddPost()
{
    Post newPost = new Post()
    {
        postTitle = inputTitle.Text,
        postBody = inputBody.Text,
        postDescription = inputDescription.Text,
        postCategory = inputCategory.SelectedValue,
        postAnonymous = Convert.ToBoolean(Int32.Parse(inputAnonymous.SelectedValue)),
    };

    using (var _dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        _dbContext.Posts.Add(newPost);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: It gives me an error for _dbContext saying "The Name "_dbContext" does not exist in the current context

Comment: For some reason the posts table field remain -null-, nothing is being updated

Comment: Remove this line `this._dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();` from `Post()` method in class Post

Comment: If I remove that, it'll remove the functionality of this line "private ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;" and then also remove the feature of AddToDatabase() in Post Class

Comment: Yes, no need for these lines as you don't call `AddToDatabase()` method

Comment: Well I've removed them, and the tables in the database are still not updated :/ Even though logically it seems to be all correct from what I can tell. I added "            AddPost();" to the formSubmit_click code so it runs it , but maybe the form isn't being submitted/

Comment: It's not returning any errors, I'm even trying to debug it but no results are returned